# SOAP API not working over HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap, https

I have recently moved my site to run on HTTPS and have just discovered my stock update script is no longer functioning.

The script opens a SOAP API connection but the response i'm receiving is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/username/public_html/stockticker/processupdates.php:22 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://www.kid...', 'urn:Mage_Api_Mo...', 1, 0) #1 /home/username/public_html/stockticker/processupdates.php(22): SoapClient->__call('login', Array) #2 /home/username/public_html/stockticker/processupdates.php(22): SoapClient->login('apiusername', 'apipassword') #3 {main} thrown in /home/username/public_html/stockticker/processupdates.php on line 22
```

I am using mod_rewrite to force everything to HTTPS, not sure if this might of had an impact?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and

```
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=84600; includeSubDomains"
```

Any idea's? I'm baffled and unfortunately this has a pretty big impact on my operations.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> [HTTP] Could not connect to host

says NO connection at all is possible, not that it is redirected or the response is wrong.

So I would try whether it is possible to `wget http://whateveryouconnectoMayBeAnIPAddress.local/`

Comment: Not with the default settings, I have to use the following to connect. otherwise I see an SSL handshake error.

Comment: C:\>wget -S -d --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://
www.domain.co.uk/api/?wsdl

Comment: Ok, this is looking like fallout from the POODLE SSLv3 bug that came around recently. Unfortunately for me as my host is running PHP5.3 I cannot use the ssl_method SOAP option to resolve it. Does anyone know how I could work around this?